# Absolute position of touches on IOS

Tags: ios, uiview, touch

I want to find the absolute position of touches on the IOS screen. The main screen is OpenGL with some webviews on it so it complicates getting the overall touch position in screen coordinates. Is there a simple thing like a global screen touch position that I can access ?

Ive tried subclassing touchesBegan touchesEnded and touchesMoved on the webviews but the webviews dont pass the touches through reliably, depending on if they decide that they are trying to recognize a gesture on the webview.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can convert any `CGPoint` or `CGRect` from any `UIView` to any `UIView`. Check something like:

```
myView.convert(myPoint, to: anotherView)
```

Assuming a point is in `myView` this will convert coordinates to `anotherView`. So you could as well use `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow` as a target view so you could do:

```
myView.convert(gestureRecognizer.location(in: myView), to: UIApplication.shared.keyWindow)
```

But I believe in your case you do not even need a window. Using `nil` instead of that should already use global coordinates and should work exactly the same for single window applications.

```
myView.convert(gestureRecognizer.location(in: myView), to: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks, but converting the points isn't the problem. It's that on the webviews the touches keep disappearing, even though I had my finger on the screen still. I just wondered if there was a way to get the screen space position of say the main "touch" no matter which view it was over. Like a mouse pointer :)

Comment: @user3162134 ah, maybe you just want to get all touch events where some are consumed by events like buttons pressed? Maybe your question is a bit unclear...

Comment: @user3162134 If that is the case I guess you should be able to add a gesture recognizer on window or your view controller or wherever high enough. This gesture recognizer needs to have a delegate to be able to recognize simultaneously with other gestures. There is a delegate method `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith` which should then just return `true`.

Comment: I've tried these, they don't seem to make any difference. I do have touchesBegan, touchesMoved, etc coming through on the webview, The problem I have though is that if you hold your finger down on a webview for long enough, the context menu comes up, e.g. Cut, Copy, Paste. From that point on, I get no more touch notifications. until I let go and touch it again.

Comment: @user3162134 that one is probably on a new window. It is not meant for you to be able to steal touch events there. But I guess you could add events on that window as well. All you need to do is iterate through all the windows in the application and append event hooks to it (a gesture recognizer).

Comment: Hi. I've iterated through all the views and subviews in the UIWebview and there are indeed several. Now however, I get multiple touchesBegan / Moved / Ended but they all still stop once the context menu appears on the webview, whether or not anything is selected. This is after a "longPress" I guess ? Maybe the easiest thing would be a way to stop anything other than single clicks on the webview ?

Comment: @user3162134 Actually I would expect you to iterate through all the windows. A new window may be created when dialog comes up. And this window is not part of the web view. But this is something you would need to check. Anyway, the application has a property "windows".

Comment: Right. I put invisible overlay views over the webviews to capture the touches first, and passed them to the main view. Hpowever, I've read and found that you cant pass through touches to a UIWebView !? Security maybe ?  So, I've made it that onc eyou click on the overlaid invisble view, it makes the webview active, and until you click outside the webview, you can't then move it.  Works fine, but not perfectly.  Thanks for your help

Comment: @user3162134  Maybe now that you have identified what is going on and have tried a few things you should ask a more specific question here and delete this one. You might get surprised what this community can provide you when you ask the question correctly.